# Valid nested JSON structure to parse using Java REST API from POST request body

Tags: java, json, api

I am looking to Parse the below JSON using springboot. The input is supplied from Postman in the request body. although I am able to read the JSON from POST method I am having issues in Parsing and mapping them using Wrapper classes. 
can you please review the below input JSON and propose the right java structure for Wrapper classes ?. If the format of the JSON itself is to be changed then let me know alternate structure keeping the information as is.

```
{
"CreditComplex": [{
    "BCNR":"973",
    "RelationshipName":"Pricing Company BV",
    "RAROE":"0.1250",
    "RegulatoryProfit":"50000",
    "EconomicProfit":"0",
    "RARORAC":"0.0000",
    "RWA":"2500000",
    "EconomicCapital":"0",
    "Borrowers":[{
        "Borrower 1":[{
            "RAROE":"0.1250",
            "RegulatoryProfit":"50000",
            "EconomicProfit":"0",
            "RARORAC":"0.0000",
            "RWA":"2500000",
            "EconomicCapital":"0",
            "Facilities": [{
                "GFID 1": [{
                    "RAROE":"0.1250",
                    "RegulatoryProfit":"50000",
                    "EconomicProfit":"0",
                    "RARORAC":"0.0000",
                    "RWA":"2500000",
                    "EconomicCapital":"0"
                }],
                "GFID 2": [{
                    "RAROE":"0.1250",
                    "RegulatoryProfit":"50000",
                    "EconomicProfit":"0",
                    "RARORAC":"0.0000",
                    "RWA":"2500000",
                    "EconomicCapital":"0"
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "Borrower 2":[{
            "RAROE":"0.1250",
            "RegulatoryProfit":"50000",
            "EconomicProfit":"0",
            "RARORAC":"0.0000",
            "RWA":"2500000",
            "EconomicCapital":"0",
            "Facilities": [{
                "GFID 3": [{
                    "RAROE":"0.1250",
                    "RegulatoryProfit":"50000",
                    "EconomicProfit":"0",
                    "RARORAC":"0.0000",
                    "RWA":"2500000",
                    "EconomicCapital":"0"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]}
```

Comment: It may be useful to include the code for your endpoint and the exception that's occurring with the above JSON

Comment: The JSON structure does not look correct from technical standpoint. The `Borrowers` should be array of borrower objects logically. Whereas what you have is a single object in array with two properties `Borrower 1` and `Borrower 2`. It should be list of borrowers.